# How to disable teamcity server url autodetection or fix server url manually?

Tags: nuget, teamcity

I have my Teamcity instance been setup by defaults. Its behind nginx, so i had moved */WWW* folder to */teamcity* folder and had set nginx location record up like that.

```
location /teamcity {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8111/teamcity;
  # and a couple of _sets here
}
```

everything works fine except Nuget feed. I can list packets from it but i cant download any packet because the packet URL.

```
    It looks like:
 1. http://some.domain.com:443/teamcity/whatever/url/for/the/packet/(correct one)
    instead of:
 2. https://some.domain.com/teamcity/(correct URL)
```

The packets at the second URL are accessible but feed returns me firs one. URLs in "General Settings" and "main-config.xml" are correct also. Is that because of URL auto detection, so can i disable it some how or is it because of another issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server URL autodetect is not related to this problem. If you have custom URL specified, then autodetect will be disabled.

Make sure you pass all necessary headers as specified in our documentation: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=74845225#HowTo...-NGINX

Comment: i'd messed to extend Tomcat *server.xml* config file connector with *proxyName* and *proxyPort* parameters. The problem is solved. Thank u.